# Empty set in a simplicial complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, simplicial-stuff

Should the empty set be considered a simplex in a simplicial complex?
Which justifications exist for the answer?

I guess it is somewhat comparable to $1$ not being a prime number.

Comment: If I remember correctly (hopefully someone can expand on this) allowing the empty set to be a simplex naturally gives you reduced homology groups which are widely used as they often makes statements about homology nicer.

Answer (score 2):

An abstract simplicial complex is a set $V$ of vertices together with a set $F$ of faces (which you seem to refer to as simplices) such that $A\subseteq B$ and $B\in F$ implies $A\in F$ (closed under inclusion). So if $F$ is nonempty then it also contains $\emptyset$ as an element. It means the empty simplex is a face.

Some other answers are addressing the question of the existence of an empty simplex understood as a simplicial complex. That also exists, it is the simplicial complex with $V=\emptyset$ and $F=\{\emptyset\}$. It is actually super useful. It should be thought of as the $(-1)$-dimensional sphere, since its suspension is the $0$-dimensional sphere. Its geometric realization is the empty topological space (with no points and the empty set as the only open set).

Comment: Note that many definitions (for example Wikipedia currently) do explicitly demand that the members of an abstract simplicial complex be nonempty.

Comment: @OscarCunningham, well, that will be very cumbersome to work with, for example defining a simple operation like join or even suspension suddenly takes a lot more words. But why not.

Answer (score 1):

This is a useful construction in homotopy theory and is probably easiest explained as the [augmented simplex category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_category#Augmented_simplex_category).

Comment: The augmented simplex category is related to simplicial sets, not to simplicial complexes.

Answer (score -1):

I think your answer is yes.  If the intersection of two simplices in a simplicial complex is a face (sub-simplex) of each, then an empty set must be a simplex.